# Can scp maintain original file structure on remote server?

Tags: ssh, scp

Supposing we have the following files to copy to a remote server:

```
/dir/test.php
/dir/inc/inc.php
```

I now want to copy both files to the remote server as follows:

```
cd /dir/
scp test.php inc/inc.php user@remote:/dir2/ (which contains an inc folder)
```

Is there an option to make scp copy the files in the respective directories on the remote server?

Currently I would end up with both files in `/dir2/` on the remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Manual page provides information about usage of [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) command and it mentions also the `-r` switch, which means "recursive". You can achieve the same such as:

```
scp -r dir/ user@remote:/dir2/
```

### Update

For more complicated use cases, use `rsync`, something like this:

```
rsync --include="test.php" --include="inc/inc.php" ./dir/ user@remote:/dir2/
```

Comment: Sure but I need to apply to files and not directories. If I have a directory with 1000 files I don't want to copy all of them.

Comment: so if you have more specific selection, you should check out `rsync`. `scp` is really only simple tool.

Comment: Also it is not obvious from your question. If you ask for something different, clarify.